# When I call vfork(), can I call any exec*() function, or must I call execve()?

Tags: c, linux, exec, vfork

[From the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html):

> The `vfork()` function has the same effect as `fork(2)`, except that the behavior is undefined if the process [...] calls any other function before successfully calling [...] one of the `exec(3)` family of functions.

This suggests that calling any `exec*()` function after `vfork()` is acceptable. However, later in the man page it says specifically:

> In particular, the programmer cannot rely on the parent remaining blocked until the child [...] calls `execve(2)` [...].

`execve(2)` is used repeatedly in the man page, and its usage suggests that it's the only `exec`-type function that is acceptable after `vfork()`.

So why is `execve` being singled out here, and am I safe to call other `exec`-type functions (like `execlp`)?

Answer (score 5):

You must call `execve`. There is no guarantee that any of the other exec-family functions do not perform actions which would be unsafe after `vfork`. For example:

- `execl` may allocate memory for the argument list. It's required to be async-signal-safe, which means it's unlikely to use `malloc`, but even if it doesn't, there's no way it could free the allocated memory (which exists in the parent's memory space) after the underlying `execve` takes place, so it would (at best) leak memory in the parent unless it manages to construct the argument list on the stack.
- `execvp` needs to access the environment to perform a path search, and also needs to construct concatenated pathnames to pass to `execve`. The latter may require allocation and the former may do all sorts of unsafe-after-`vfork` things (note: `execvp` is not even async-signal-safe).

etc.

Really you should simply not use `vfork`. It's almost impossible to make its use safe. In particular it's unsafe in any program that's using signal handlers since the signal handler could run in the child while it's sharing the parent's memory unless you block all signals (and in that case the child would inherit a fully-blocked signal mask after exec, which is almost surely not what you want).

If you're looking for a more-efficient alternative to `fork`, use `posix_spawn`.

Comment: So Linux's `vfork` is not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/vfork.html) compliant? Shouldn't the man page be updated to remove the misleading part ("one of the `exec(3)` family of functions")?

Comment: POSIX removed `vfork` a long time ago. Maybe it does meet those old requirements, but I would not necessarily expect it to. You'd probably need to read the source, and even then it might change, so I wouldn't do it. Just don't use `vfork`. It's dangerous and rather useless.

Comment: `vfork` is useful if your program will be ported to Microsoft's Windows via for example `cygwin` or `mingw`. As `fork` is very very very slow on Microsoft's OSes. However I would find a library that does the `pipe`, `vfork`, `exec`, etc. in a single call. So that you keep out of the mess.

Comment: @richard: In other words, find a proper implementation of `posix_spawn` for cygwin/mingw. Alternatively you could try [midipix](http://midipix.org) where `fork` isn't atrociously slow and broken.

Comment: This answer is wrong because it fails to consider stack memory. Most functions listed in `man signal-safety` are safe with vfork() with a few exceptions like read() so just use pread() instead. posix_spawn is a cringeworthy api and xnu is the only kernel I've seen that supports it. Learn vfork() because it's dangerously fast and supported everywhere like the rest of the C language. Check out the source code to Almquist Shell (it's /bin/sh on Linux and FreeBSD) to learn which behaviors are de facto guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux all `exec*` functions are actually wrapper library functions on top of `execve` syscall. So by calling `execlp` you are actually also calling `execve`.

Comment: Is there some kind of reference/documentation for that, or is just arcane knowledge? It seems weird for the `vfork()` docs to mention `execve` if this kind of behavior isn't explicitly documented somehwere.

Comment: What if the library wrapper allocates dynamic memory? (E.g. to build up the array.)

Comment: @Cornstalks only `execve` is in section 2 (syscalls) of Linux man page the other `exec*` functions are in section 3 (library calls).

Comment: @KerrekSB would it change anything comparing to `fork`?

Comment: None of the wrappers have any need. Anyway, I thought you could modify e.g. the file-descriptors, current directory, priviliges and the like before changing the executable...

Comment: @ouah: After `fork` the image is replaced, so all is well (mostly, notwithstanding problems with multithreaded allocators). But with `vfork`, you're still in the parent memory until the `execve` syscall, so that memory would leak. Somehow you'd want a guarnatee that the library wrappers don't "do" anything.

Comment: @Cornstalks this info is also stated in `man 3 exec` and you can verify `execve` is called when you call for example `execlp` by running your program with `strace` tool.

Answer (score 1):

After reading over the manual again, it becomes clear that there are two descriptions of `vfork`:

**The POSIX Standard Description** says that after `vfork`, one of the `exec(3)` functions must be called.

**The Linux Description** says that after `vfork`, `execve(2)` (and *only* `execve`) must be called.

It's not clear to me whether the POSIX Standard Description requires a conforming implementation to allow any one of the `exec` functions to be called. One possible reading of the Standard Description is that the implementation may decide which `exec` functions are allowed (and only requires that at least one of them be allowed after a `vfork`).

Either way, it's clear that Linux allows `execve` (and only `execve`*) to be called after a `vfork`. The POSIX standard might allow other `exec` functions, but Linux does not.

<sub>*Well, sure, it can call `_exit` too, but I'm ignoring `_exit` in this Q&A.</sub>